# Can tsconfig.json be placed inside package.json?

Tags: javascript, typescript, babeljs, package.json, tsconfig

Just like babel.rc?

Or maybe its contents can be imported into `webpack.config.js`?

```
{
  "name": "Foo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators"]
  },
  "tsconfig": { ... },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, there is no official support. However, there is [github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32830) for this feature.